# Why does php echo print out ?> message?

Tags: php, echo

With the following code below,

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PHP Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want only the `Hello World` statement to be printed, but it also prints out `;?>`.

After I inspected the element, it came out like this.

```
 <body>
    <!--?php echo '<p-->
    Hello World
    <p></p>
    "; ?>"
 </body>
```

Comment: Can't reproduce it. Have you even installed PHP ?

Comment: plus, is it `.php` ext?

Comment: yes for both questions

Comment: Easy to reproduce: http://plnkr.co/edit/45hLNQOoJij7pm4mJmt6?p=preview This is what you get if your file is not served by PHP and treated as static HTML.

Comment: @user2585578 1) You also need a webserver to run PHP and it has to be turned on? 2) The file needs to be in the server directory?

Comment: Read about Apache, how to install it and how to run PHP with it.

Comment: Did you run a file server? For easier start, you can use `php -S 127.0.0.1:1337` in your project root where the `index.php` lies and then see the page at `127.0.0.1:1337` in your browser. In the long run, you want to setup an apache or nginx.

Comment: did you use a framework or smarty or template system anyway? or views ..

Comment: what I did was to install php via web platform installer since window's IIS doens't have the package for php.

Answer (score 0):

Your website is treated as plain HTML. Ensure that you have a webserver running:

If you have accesst to the command line on a Gnu/Linux derivate you can start PHP's [internal server](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) by:

```
php -S 127.0.0.1:1337
```

This command has to be started in your web root and you should have an `index.php` living there. Then your code runs fine.

In the long run, you want to set up a nginx or an apache2. Another aspect to look into is using vagrant to setup a virtual Linux machine that creates your development enviroment.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it seems that everybody is recommending me to install nginx or apache to get the php working. But any way to get it working under Internet Information Service from Windows?

Comment: @user2585578 If you really want to stick to Windows' IIS, you should follow their howto: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh994592.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to open the file directly in your web browser, but unlike HTML, your browser is incapable of understanding PHP.

**PHP needs to be run server-side** behind Apache, Nginx or any viable web server, your web browser will then request pages from that webserver, which will request PHP to serve your browser the fully generated page.

Practically, if you're trying PHP for the first time, you want to **install a development LAMP stack** such as [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) (for Windows only), [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) (for Linux, Windows, OS X) or [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/) (for OS X, Windows). Installing and running this will easily set up a web server on your computer.

I will not write a full tutorial on how to use a LAMP stack but I can recommend you to [read that article from Kasia Mikoluk on Udemy](https://blog.udemy.com/xampp-tutorial/). It should teach you the basics.